# Inheritance: weaker accessibility of a method in subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, superclass

what is the need of having a rule like this in java :

"a subclass cannot weaken the accessibility of a method defined in the superclass"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a class with a public method

```
public class Foo {
    public void method() {}
}
```

This method is accessible and you can therefore do

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.method();
```

If you add a subclass

```
public class Bar extends Foo {
    @Override
    public /* private */ void method() {}
}
```

If it was `private`, you should not be able to do

```
Foo bar = new Bar();
bar.method();
```

In this example, a `Bar` is a `Foo`, so it must be able to replace a `Foo` wherever one is expected.

In order to satisfy the above statement, a sub class cannot make an inheritable member less accessible. It can however make it more accessible. (This basically only applies to methods.)

Answer (score 2):

**What it means**

The subclass method cannot have a more restrictive visibity than the superclass method.

For example, if the superclass defined

```
protected void a() { } // visible to package and subclasses
```

the subclass can override it with one of

```
public void a() { }    // visible to all
protected void a() { } // visible to package and subclasses
```

but not

```
void a() { }           // visible to package
private void a() { }   // visible to itself
```

---

**Why it is**

Suppose the definition was

```
class A {
    public void a() { }
}

class B extends A {
    private void a() { }
}
```

Now, consider the following code

```
A instance = new B();
instance.a(); // what does this call?
```

On the one hand, any `B` has a publically accessible `a` method. On the other hand, the `a` method of a `B` instance is only accessible to `B`.

---

*More generally, a subclass(interface) must fulfill the contract of its superclass(interface).*

Visibility is only one example of this principle. Another example is that a non-abstract class must implement all methods of any interface it implements.

Comment: i am not asking for meaning . i am asking for reason why we need a rule like this ?

Answer (score 1):

```
class Person {
    public String name() {
        return "rambo";
    }
}

// subclass reduces visibility to private
class AnonymousPerson {
    private String name() {
        return "anonymous";
    }
}
```

It's legal to call the following method with either a `Person`, or an `AnonymousPerson` as the argument. But, if the method visibility was restricted, it wouldnt' be able to call the `name()` method.

```
class Tester {
    static void printPersonName(Person p) {
        System.out.println(p.name());
    }
}

//ok
Tester.printPersonName(new Person());
```

this call is legal, because a `Person` is a `AnonymousPerson`, but it would have to fail inside the method body. This violates "type safety".

```
Tester.printPersonName(new AnonymousPerson());
```

Answer (score 0):

To fulfill the interface contract. Let's say I have an interface, `IFlying`, as:

```
public interface IFlying {
    public void fly();
}
```

And I have an implementation that weakens accessibility:

```
public class Bird implements IFlying {
    private void fly(){
        System.out.println("flap flap");
    }
}
```

I now have some library function that accepts an IFlying, and calls `fly` upon it. The implementation is private. What happens now? Of course, it means that the fly method cannot be accessed.

Hence, the accessibility may not be made more restrictive in an implementation.